# Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets and $f: X\rightarrow Y$. Efficient way to prove that the following are equivalent.

Tags: analysis

Let $X$ and $Y$ be sets and $f: X\rightarrow Y$. Prove that the following are equivalent:

1. $f$ is one-to-one on $X$
2. $f(A-B) = f(A)-f(B),\forall A,B \subseteq X$
3. $f^{-1}(f(E)) = E$, $\forall E \subseteq X$
4. $f(A\cap B) = f(A)\cap f(B)$, $\forall A,B \subseteq X$

Hello, my question pertains to how I should go about proving this. My first instinct was like a brute force method. By that I mean proving that:

- $1 \Rightarrow 2, 3, \text{ and } 4$
- $2 \Rightarrow 1, 3, \text{ and } 4$
- $3 \Rightarrow 1, 2, \text{ and } 4$
- $4 \Rightarrow 1, 2, \text{ and } 3$

But that's too time consuming so I was wondering if it would suffice to show that:
$$1 \iff 2 \iff 3 \iff 4,$$
or if there is a more efficient way to tackle this problem.

Comment: Yes.Infact it is enough to show that $1 \Rightarrow 2 \Rightarrow 3  \Rightarrow  4 \Rightarrow 1$.This one is much easier way than the way you have described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes,infact a much easier way would be to show that $ 1 \Rightarrow 2  \Rightarrow 3 \Rightarrow 4 \Rightarrow 1$.